# Emscripten sandwiched by asynchronous Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, emscripten

I'm trying to use Emscripten to write a Software to run in browser but also on other architectures (e.g. Android, PC-standalone app).

The Software structure is something like this:

```
main_program_loop() {
   if (gui.button_clicked()) {
      run_async(some_complex_action, gui.text_field.to_string())
   }
   if (some_complex_action_has_finished())
   {
      make_use_of(get_result_from_complex_action());
   }
}

some_complex_action(string_argument)
{
    some_object = read_local(string_argument);
    interm_res = simple_computation(some_object);
    other_object = expensive_computation(interm_res);
    send_remote(some_object.member_var, other_object);
    return other_object.member_var;
}
```

Let's call `main_program_loop` the GUI or frontend, `some_complex_action` the intermediate layer, and `read_local`, `send_remode` and `expensive_computation` the backend or lower layer.

Now the frontend and backend would be architecture specific (e.g. for Javascript `read_local` could use `IndexDB`, `send_remote` could use `fetch`),
but the intermediate layer should make up more then 50% of the code (that's why I do not want to write it two times in two different languages, and instead write it once in C and transpile it to Javascript, for Android I would use JNI).

Problems come in since in Javascript the functions on the lowest layer (`fetch` etc) run asyncronously (return a promise or require a callback).

One approach I tried was to use promises and send IDs through the intermediate layer

```
var promises = {};
var last_id = 0;
handle_click() {
    var id = Module.ccall('some_complex_action', 'number', ['string'], [text_field.value]);
    promises[id].then((result) => make_us_of(result));
}

recv_remote: function(str) {
    promises[last_id] = fetch(get_url(str)).then((response) => response.arrayBuffer());
    last_id += 1;
    return last_id - 1;
}
```

It works for the simple case of

```
some_complex_action(char *str)
{
    return recv_remote(str);
}
```

But for real cases it seem to be getting really complicated, maybe impossible. (I tried some approach where I'd given every function a state and every time a backend function finishes, the function is recalled and advances it's state or so, but the code started getting complicated like hell.) To compare, if I was to call `some_complex_action` from C or Java, I'd just call it in a thread separate from the GUI thread, and inside the thread everything would happen synchronously.

I wished I could just call `some_complex_action` from an async function and put `await` inside `recv_remote` but of cause I can put await only directly in the async function, not in some function called down the line. So that idea did not work out either.

Ideally if somehow I could stop execution of the intermediate Emscripten transpiled code until the backend function has completed, then return from the backend function with the result and continue executing the transpiled code.

Has anyone used Emterpreter and can imagine that it could help me get to my goal?

Any ideas what I could do?